# How to apply a mulitstep function to several datasets and then combine the results into a new dataset

Tags: r, function

I would like to apply a set of functions to multiple datasets to 1) edit the datasets (e.g. add new variables and remove NAs), 2) concatenate the resulting datasets, and 3) calculate summary statistics on the new datasets and combine the resulting statistics in a table.

Below is my current code to manually apply the functions to the datasets (which all contain the same variable structure, but have different lengths)

```
library(tibble)
library(doBy)
library(plyr)

# STEP 0: create example datasets. 
# In reality, I have numerous sets of data that are systematically named, such as
#   a1 = population A, scenario 1
#   b1 = population B, scenario 1
#   b2 = population B, scenario 2
#    etc...
a1 <- tibble(min = c(10:14, NA), count = c(10, 25, 0, 29, 36, 5)); a1
b2 <- tibble(min = c(8:11, NA, NA), count = c(10, 5, 0, 23, 36, 5)); b2

## STEP 1: choose which datasets to process
tab <- a1

## STEP 2: Add identifying variable to each dataset (in preparation for rbinding). Ideally this is integrated into step 3 below and it would be automatically generated based on the original dataset name (or some type of for loop) Currently, I do it manually below. In the last step, I apply the summaryBy function using pop and scenario vars.
tab$pop <- "a"
tab$scenario <- "1"

## STEP 3: Apply below steps to each population dataset. I will include many more steps, but for brevity I only include a couple here 
tab <- tab[!is.na(tab$min), ]     # remove rows with NA values for min var  
tab$min05 <- tab$min * 0.5    # create new var

a1_new <- tab  # save as new edited dataset

## STEP 4: Repeat STEP 1-3 for each dataset. 
tab <- b2
tab$pop <- "b"  
tab$scenario <- "2"
tab <- tab[!is.na(tab$min), ]    
tab$min05 <- tab$min * 0.5     

b2_new <- tab  

## STEP 5: Concatenate the edited population datasets
dt0 <- rbind(a1_new, b2_new); dt0


## STEP 6:  Create summary statistics table
sumTbl  <- summaryBy(min + min05 ~ pop + scenario, data = dt0,
                     FUN = function(x) { c(
                       min = min(x), 
                       median = median(x), 
                       mean = mean(x), 
                       max=max(x) 
                     ) } )
sumTbl
```

Below is my attempt to create a function and apply the function over a list of the datasets.

```
my.list = list(a1, b2)

myfxn <- function(duck){
  tab <- as.data.frame(duck)
  
  tab$pop <- substr(deparse(substitute(duck)), 1, 1)  # DOES NOT WORK
  tab$scenario <- substr(deparse(substitute(duck)), 2, 2)  # DOES NOT WORK
  
  tab <- tab[!is.na(tab$min), ]     # remove rows with NA values for min var  
  tab$min05 <- tab$min * 0.5    # create new var
  
  return(tab)
}

all.lst <- lapply(my.list, myfxn)
```

However, there are several issues with my approach:

1. I am not able to properly extract the correct characters from dataset name to create the pop and scenario vars
2. The resulting "all.list" is a list of data frames and I'm not sure how to combine them (in order to run the summaryBy function.)
3. Could I add the summary stat function into myFxn and then run a separate ldplyr function to combine the results?

Many thanks in advance for your help. I've already searched many posts, but apologies in advance if I've missed something!

Comment: I will imagine that your datasets are imported somehow, or generated. Rather than storing these as variables, store them as elements in a `list`, create a `function` for performing each of your steps and then use a `for-loop` or `*apply` (such as `lapply`) to apply the function across each element of the list.

Comment: Yes, I import each dataset. Regarding your suggestion, I may be misunderstanding, but in my attempted answer I store the objects in a list and then attempt to create a function and use lapply. But some of steps didn’t quite work.

Comment: @ellejay, consider approaching your problem as a set of smaller problems. Try simply applying a simple function to all your dataframes first. When you verify that it works, then start improving the complexity of your function. You'll also notice that your smaller issues will probably have similar questions here in SO.